# ajax request to login in Joomla 3.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla

I am trying to add a login option in a form to fill the inputs after login .
I added the following script to login using ajax but I cannot make it work and it returns a 404 error.
Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

```
$('#mydiv').on('click','#login',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $username = $('#username').val();
    $password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php?option=com_ajax&task=loginauth',
        data: {username: $username, password: $password},
        success: function(responseData){
            window.location = $url;
        },
        error: function(responseData){
            console.log('login script error');
        }
    });
});
```

The url `index.php?option=com_ajax&task=loginauth` seems valid as I can reach it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I make ajax calls to a task on the controller.

Here is the url format I am using in one of my extensions that uses ajax calls to a component:

```
index.php?format=raw&option=<component_name_goes_here>&task=<task_goes_here>
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it by adding the format in the query !